# Hive Lateral View Explode with where clause - what runs first

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am trying to understand if WHERE clause runs after or before with LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE in hive.

For example if I have

```
   SELECT *
FROM
   (
    SELECT
        a1,
        a2,
        b.ds,
        conv_list.threshold_conv[0]
            AS t
    FROM
       t1 b
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE({list})
                conv_list as threshold_conv
    WHERE
        b.ds between '{DATE-29}' and '{DATE}'
  )
```

will ds filter run before or after lateral view explode?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: you can use explain command and get the detail. But at per my understanding  LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE will be done first then where ...

Comment: @sandeeprawat - so you assume that if the filtering is for example on a partitioned column(s), the whole table would be scanned, the rows will be exploded and only then the filtering will take place?

Comment: yes .. that is how it should ..

Comment: @sandeeprawat wouldn't that defeat the entire purpose of partitioning?

Answer (score 3):

- if your filter column is a partition in your table, that is the main purpose of the partitioning, even if you where clause is out of your subquery (predicate pushdown)
- Lateral view can be a expensive operation sometimes, for this reason Hive apply the filter before apply the lateral view, see the following execution plan based on your query (not the same).

  ```
        STAGE PLANS:   Stage: Stage-1
      Map Reduce
        Map Operator Tree:
            TableScan
              alias: a
              filterExpr: ((mycolumndpartitioned > 0) and (mycolumn= 112623934)) (type: boolean)
              Statistics: Num rows: 23953585 Data size: 52793067242 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Filter Operator
                predicate: (mycolumn= 112623934) (type: boolean)
                Statistics: Num rows: 11976792 Data size: 26396532519 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Lateral View Forward
                  Statistics: Num rows: 11976792 Data size: 26396532519 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  Select Operator
                    Statistics: Num rows: 11976792 Data size: 26396532519 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                    Lateral View Join Operator
                      outputColumnNames: _col13
                      Statistics: Num rows: 23953584 Data size: 52793065038 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                      Select Operator
                        expressions: _col13.myArray (type: string)
                        outputColumnNames: _col0
                        Statistics: Num rows: 23953584 Data size: 52793065038 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                        File Output Operator
                          compressed: false
                          Statistics: Num rows: 23953584 Data size: 52793065038 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
  ```
- Now, if your filter use some fields from the exploded array, i would suppose that Hive will try to apply all the possible filters that do not use any columns from the exploded data before apply the lateral view and then apply your filters for the exploded data